# How to do regular expressions in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

So there are many questions and answers here around the subject of regular expressions. The downside is that the vast majority of answers are simply **the** regular expression...

I have also googled - and found hundreds of sites. Trying to wade through everything for a quick-to-understand and implement answer isn't too easy. they are either in a different language - which maybe shouldn't make any difference, though you escape differently in C# to VB and that leads to confusion as to what is an escape character vs a regex switch.

The part I am struggling with is understanding them so I can implement some, apparently, simple expressions.

**My scenario:**

I have to check every character in a given string, and if the regular expression doesn't allow any of the characters then it should return false.

**Example:**

I have tried the following expressions (copy/pasted from various answers here....)

```
Dim r As New Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$")
```

also tried

```
Dim r As New Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9\s]")
```

also tried

```
Dim r as New Regex("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*")
```

**I have been implementing this like:**

```
Dim r As New Regex(_fontJIAdieuxRegEx) '' where _fontJIAdieuxRegEx is one of the above regex strings.
Dim supported = r.IsMatch(fontName)
```

I have been trying to validate something like the following:

`darren` should return `True`

`da-rren` should return `False` due to the `-` hyphen

`da rren` should return `True`

Now, simply put, any of these expressions will either return `True` for all of the strings or `False` for all of the strings; so i am clearly doing something wrong.

what I would really appreciate is someone pointing out where I am going wrong and also explain a little about the make-up of the regular expression.

Once I understand them a little more I need to be able to have different expressions to allow other characters, such as ! @ " ' . etc. So please don't just paste an expression to solve the simple example above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first pattern is the correct one to use. The second pattern will return true if just one character in the string matches. The third pattern will return true if zero or more characters in the beginning of the string matches, which it always does.

I don't know what you did to make it not work, but using it like this works:

```
Dim _fontJIAdieuxRegEx As String = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"

Dim r As New Regex(_fontJIAdieuxRegEx)

Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("darren"))
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("da-rren"))
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("da rren"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: I now get my first pattern to match, thanks :) - seems I had a typo in my source code that wasn't on the question. Would you mind explaining, roughly, what the `^`,`*` and `$` do? and how would I escape for things like `'` and `"` ?

Comment: The `^` character is an _anchor_ to the beginning of the string. Be careful, because this character can have another meaning when used in a different place. The `*` character here means to match the preceding part of the expression zero or more times, and the `$` character is another _anchor_, this time to the end of the string. Taken all together, they mean to match this set at the start of the string zero or more times, all the way to the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. It's starting to click a little more now i think. I just tried adding a bunch of characters to the character class and ended up with an `ArgumentException` - `parsing "^[a-zA-Z0-9 '_-()&#!+:;=]*$" - [x-y] range in reverse order`. I figure it's the `'` character causing the issue. how to i escape in VB for characters like `'` and `"` and other reserved characters? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Darren: The apostrophe is not a problem, but the dash is. You have the range `_-(` which means all characters from `_` to `(`, but you get that parsing error as `_` comes after `(`. As you don't want that to be a range at all, you should escape the dash using `\-`.

Comment: The other thing you have to remember is * is greedy by default, meaning it matches as much as possible. if you add a ? after it, it becomes non-greedy, matching as few as possible.

Comment: @SimonHalsey - so in this case, where i need to make sure everything in the string is valid i would want to use `*`, wouldn't i?

Comment: @Guffa - excellent, thanks, added that in and it worked :D gaining a much better understand of it now, thanks again :) - marking this as answered as you have provided just what I was after; an easy explanation for the fluff-and-nonsense that is RegEx :)

Comment: @Darren, yes. Greediness is something you need to take into account when you're only checking part of a string

Comment: You only need to worry about greediness if you are capturing something that you match. When you are just checking for a match, it doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 3):

The regex classes are located in the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. To make them available, place Imports `System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the start of your source code.

```
Regex.IsMatch("subject", "regex")
```

*checks if the regular expression matches the subject string.*

```
Regex.Replace("subject", "regex", "replacement")
```

*performs a search-and-replace.*

```
Regex.Split("subject", "regex")
```

*splits the subject string into an array of strings as described above. All these methods accept an optional additional parameter of type `RegexOptions`, like the constructor.*

Source / more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: Thanks Daan - and welcome to SO. I'm more trying to understand how the regex is put together rather than how to call the code; I've got that part working. it's my patterns that suck :)

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd expression matches **anything**. The `*` character at the end of the character class tell the regular expression engine to match that character class *zero* or more times. Since there are not other conditions in the expression, any string is valid. The third expression matches anything that has at least one valid character.

The first expression should work, but I'm not a fan of the start and end anchors (`^` and `$`) if you don't need them. What I would do here instead is *invert* the expression... look for characters that are not valid. The expression would look like this:

> [^A-Za-z0-9 ]

In this case, the `^` character used as part of the character class means to *negate* the class: this will match any character that is **not** in that class, and since we don't have any anchors it will match if such a character occurs anywhere in the string. Now, of course, I must also invert the result in the VB.Net code:

```
Dim r As New Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")
Dim supported = Not r.IsMatch(fontName)
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, certainly looks a lot tidier!